# Unable to save content more than 8Mb in a CSV file with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, export-to-csv, html5-filesystem

I get a string as response from my backend with more than 8MB of csv content.

with this code :

```js
myService.getCsvExportContent(vm.searchParams).then(function (content) {
        var encodedUri = encodeURI(content);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute("download", "MCsExport.csv");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      });
```

When the result is less that 8Mb, it creates the whole file but when it's more than 8Mb, it saves the half of data to the file and I lose data. (I can see the size by debugging in my browser)

I tried [angular-file-saver](https://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/) but I still got errors the injection of the dependency doesn't work for me in AngularJS.

I tried creating Blob object with the content, same result.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Well it definitely won't work using a regular URL, as it has a very small limit you will hit rather quickly. Try adding your Blob code as well, as it is the right approach and can be used to even export video files, so it should be capable of doing this correctly. Setting up your Blob correctly is important though (in chunks, best), so please share that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, that works for me:

```
myService.getCsvExportContent(vm.searchParams).then(function (content) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var blob = new Blob([content],{type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute("download", "MCsExport.csv");
    link.click();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping. Finally injecting ngFileSaver worked for me. `bower cache clean` then `bower install angular-file-saver --save-dev` and my injected object is recognized.

And so `FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "filePath.csv")` worked pretty fine.

```
var blob = new Blob([content], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'});    
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "Export.csv");
```